# Django REST - create object with PrimaryKey

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**Model:**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='companies')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
```

**And I use the built-in User model**

**Serializers**

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name', 'created')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    companies = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_joined', 'is_staff', 'is_active',
                  'is_superuser', 'last_login', 'companies')
```

**View:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def companies_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = CompanySerializer(data=data)
        print(serializer)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

- How should a JSON file be sent to the server (does it include all fields in the Company + user_id model)?
- How do I attach a User object before saving in a view?

Answer (score 1):

```
@csrf_exempt
def companies_create(request):

    user = get_user_from_somewhere()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = CompanySerializer(data=data)
        print(serializer)
        if serializer.is_valid():

            serializer.save(user=user)

            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Answer (score 1):

use django **get_user_model**,

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

user_model = get_user_model()

@csrf_exempt
def companies_create(request):

    user = get_user_from_somewhere()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = CompanySerializer(data=data)
        print(serializer)
        if serializer.is_valid():

            serializer.save(user=user_model)

            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```